# 2d matrix not storing values, all values displayed as 0

Tags: c

I'm trying to read two sizes from a file, and then a matrix. The code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int n,m;

    fp = fopen("grille.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &m);
    int mat[n][m];
    int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &temp);
            mat[n][m] = temp;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",mat[n][m]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

If I print out `temp` while reading it, all values are shown correctly. However when trying to print them from the matrix, a null matrix of correct size is printed instead. I learnt to program in c++ and some of this c stuff just baffles me.

Comment: `mat[n][m] = temp;` --> `mat[i][j] = temp;` and ditto for the print loop. You are writing all values *out of range* of the array, too, since an array is indexed from `0` to `dimension-1`

Comment: @WeatherVane someone shoot me. Post as full answer please.

Comment: "I learnt to program in c++ and some of this c" - Hmmm... would you be surprised C++ is different than Modula? If yes, then why surprised C is is also different? All three are different languages.

Comment: @Olaf would be a valid point, except my whining is completely irrelevant here since this was a really stupid mistake that could have been solved using the rubber duck method. My prejudice against C got the best of me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't use the loop control variables to index the array. Instead you only use the array dimensions, as in

```
mat[n][m] = temp;
```

which of course should be

```
mat[i][j] = temp;
```

There is a similar slip-up in the print loop too.

There was also an *undefined behaviour* side-effect of this mistake, because indexing by the array dimension, will index out of range of the array.